# How to generate a numeric identifier for entries based on a string

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm working in Redshift SQL syntax, and want to know a way to convert a string id for each entry in a table to a numeric id (since numeric joins between tables are supposedly much quicker and more efficient than string joins).

Currently the ids look like this - a bunch of strings with both numbers and letters

```
01r00001ABCDeAAF
01r00001IJKLmAAN
...
01r00001OPQRtAAN
```

What I would like is to turn this into a purely numeric identifier, using the string id as an input and ensuring that each output is unique and corresponds only to a single input with no collisions (which can be replicated across tables so that accurate joins are possible).

I've tried using some hash functions within SQL like CHECKSUM() and BINARY_CHECKSUM() over the columns, but I'm a little unclear which would be the most applicable here - I understand some are case-sensitive and others aren't, while some generate collisions and others don't.

Comment: . . I'm not sure if joins on strings are *that much faster* than joins on numbers.  Do you have a reference for the performance impact?

Comment: read it here: https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/02/15/are-int-joins-faster-than-string-joins-2/

and heard it anecdotally from other people too...

Comment: Numeric joins *might* be quicker than string joins, but only if the numeric id is a column of the table. Definitely **not** when you use a function in the join condition.

Comment: @HoneyBadger I was planning to generate a new column within the table(s) before doing the join, rather than a function within the join condition

Comment: You could just add the new column and generate a new numerical id using something like ROW_NUMBER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your reference for strings versus integers is based on an entirely different database.  I would not generalize from SQL Server performance to other databases, particularly a massively parallel columnar database.  There is also a lot of information that is taken out of context and generalized to wrong situations.

Second, you can test on tables in Amazon Redshift.  Generating the data and doing the tests should be faster than modifying existing data.  You will probably find no need to change anything.

You need to understand what is happening "under the hood" before making a change like this, particularly if you think it is for performance reasons.

Strings can be troublesome for a variety of reasons.  First, they can have different collations or character sets -- information that is hidden.  Such differences would preclude the use of indexes -- a major hit in a database such as SQL Server.  Not using indexes is generally not an issue in Redshift.

Strings can also have variable lengths.  This makes indexes slightly less efficient.  They also require a wee bit more overhead to compare than numbers, because those collations and character sets need to be taken into account.  They also need to be compared character-by-character, whereas most hardware has built-in comparisons for numbers.  The extra cycles here is usually minimal compared to the cost of moving data.

When you do a `join` in Amazon Redshift, the first thing it is going to do is collocate the data, probably by hashing the values and sending the data to the same nodes in the parallel environment.  Moving the data is expensive.  Hashing the values, much less so.

In Redshift, you should be more concerned about how your data is distributed.  Although I haven't tested it, adding a new column that is a number might make the query *more* expensive, because in a columnar database, the number of columns referenced has an impact on performance.